# Emberjs returning a TypeError: stateManager is undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am currently building an emberjs  and i am trying to get the router working. 
I wanted to test the code and it's always returning me a TypeError: stateManager is undefined error.Is there anything im doing wrong? 
FYI I am not using any backend for now only json data. 
Edit : i am using Ember 0.9.8.1

```
App = Em.Application.create({}); 

/* Main menu*/
App.MenuModel = Em.Object.extend({
    id : null,
    titre : null,
    questions : null,
    route: null
});

/* Submenu */
App.SubMenuModel = Em.Object.extend({
    titre : null, 
    id : null
});

/*Questions*/
App.QuestionsModel = Em.Object.extend({
    id : null,
    question : null,
    points: 0
}); 

/*************************************** Controller */
App.ApplicationController = Em.ArrayController.extend();

/* Main Menu controller */
App.MenuController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    content:[],
        init : function(){
            var self = this;
            var data = menuComplet;
            console.log(menuComplet);
            console.log(this);
                data.forEach(function(item){
                    console.log(self);
                    self.pushObjects(App.MenuModel.create(item));
                }, data);
        }
});

/* Sub Menu controller */
App.SubMenuController = Em.ArrayController.extend({

});

/* Question controller */
App.QuestionController = Em.ArrayController.extend({

});


App.ApplicationView = Em.View.create({
    templateName: 'application'
 });


App.MenuView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName : "navigation", 
    contentBinding : "App.MenuController.content"
});

/****************************************** Router */
App.Router = Em.Router.extend({
    enableLogging : true,
    location : 'hash',
    root: Ember.State.extend({
    // STATES
        index: Ember.State.create({
            route: '/',
            connectOutlets: function (router) {
                router.get('App.ApplicationController').connectOutlet('index');
            }
        })
    })  
});
App.initialize();
```

Comment: What version of Ember.js are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use last version of Ember.JS. By last version I don't mean last stable, I mean last build of Ember.JS (build it yourself or download it [here](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/emberjs/data/ember-data-latest.js))
2. Replace  Ember.State with Ember.Route.
3. Change router.get('App.ApplicationController') with router.get('applicationController')
4. connectOutlet('index') seems also to be wrong. It looks up for IndexView and IndexController so I guess you need replace 'index' with 'menu'
5. Replace ApplicationView.create with ApplicationView.extend (read more about it [here](https://gist.github.com/2728699))

Comment: it returns root: Em.Route.extend({ undefined

Comment: There's no connectOutlet in 0.9.8.1

Comment: what replaces the connect outlets ...im trying to follow on the site docs here and i am currenbtly stuck

Comment: Just use last version. There're too many things changed since 0.9.8.1. Documentation on emberjs.com is sometimes deprecated. You can build it yourself or find somewhere (e.g https://github.com/pangratz/dashboard)

Comment: ember-0.9.8.1 used, use this ember source - http://cloud.github.com/downloads/emberjs/ember.js/ember-latest.min.js . Also ember-latest doesn't include handlebars.js

Comment: great job the bug was version related you were right ...why dont you post the link to the versions and the answer so i can consider the problem solved ...

Comment: Does it look well now? I'm just new to stackoverflow and can't chat with you about it

Comment: post the answer and i will help you get the rep to chat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14348/discussion-between-lunatikzx-and-zaplitny)